# How to make the submenu to be at the same horizontal as its parent's menu with this css?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
/*
 LEVEL ONE : MAIN MENU
 */

ul.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
ul.dropdown li.menuppal {
  float: left;
  zoom: 1;
  background: #B2DAFB repeat-x top left;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #222;
}
ul.dropdown li.menuppal a {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #000000;
}
/* Doesn't work in IE */

ul.dropdown li.menuppal:hover {
  background: #ccc url('../images/menuDark.png') repeat-x 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
}
/*
        FIN LEVEL ONE
 */

/*
 LEVEL TWO
 */

ul.dropdown ul {
  width: 220px;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #40617C;
}
ul.dropdown ul li {
  float: none;
}
/* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */

ul.dropdown li.menuppal ul li a {
  border-right: none;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.dropdown li.menuppal ul li a:hover {
  background: #07243a;
}
ul.dropdown li.menuppal ul li a:visited {
  word-break: break-all;
}
/*
 LEVEL THREE
 */

ul.dropdown ul ul {
  left: 100%;
}
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://iscriptdesign.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/js/jquery.dropdownPlain.js"></script>

<div>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Administration</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Indoor</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Netting</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Padding</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Structure</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">All-in-One Team Cart</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Air &amp; Electrical Reels</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Field Drags</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Field Marking Equipment</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Batter's Box Templates</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Dryline Markers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Field Paint</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Field Sprayers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Stencils</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Field Tarps</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Area Tarps</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Growth Covers / Protectors</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Infield Tarps</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Tarp Accessories</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Hand Tools</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Irrigation, Hoses, Nozzles</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hoses &amp; Hose Reels</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Irrigation</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nozzles</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Layout Tools</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Moisture Removal</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mound Fortification</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mowers &amp; Stripers</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Soil Management</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Soil Amendments</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Spreaders &amp; Sweepers</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Exercice</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Baseball - Softball</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Base Accessories</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bases &amp; Home Plates</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Game Accessories</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Pitching Rubbers</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Batting Practice Equipment</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Backstops</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Infield Screens</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Jugs Pitching Machines</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Turf Mats</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Turf Protectors</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Replacement Accessories</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Indoor</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Portable Mounds</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Batting Practice Mounds</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Game Mounds</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Practice Mounds</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Football</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">First Down Markers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Football Accessories</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Football Goalposts</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Soccer</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Soccer Goals</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Soccer Accessories</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Contribuables et biens</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ladders &amp; Sticks</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Hurdles</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Training Accessories</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Smart-Cart Training System</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Smart-Hurdle Collection</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Recettes</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Field Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Training</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Edition</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Field Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Training</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Outils</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Field Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Training</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to make a dropdown menu :

At runtime the submenu is not at the same horizontal level as its parent :

[image]

So how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the css below:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 100;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/*
 LEVEL ONE : MAIN MENU
 */
ul.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown li.menuppal {
    float: left;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #000 url(../images/menuLight.png) repeat-x top left;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #222;
}

ul.dropdown li.menuppal a {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: #000000;
}

/* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.menuppal:hover {
    background: #ccc url('../images/menuDark.png') repeat-x 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
}
/*
        FIN LEVEL ONE
 */

/*
 LEVEL TWO
 */
ul.dropdown ul {
    width: 220px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #40617C;
}





ul.dropdown ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}

/* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown li.menuppal ul li a {
    border-right: none;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.dropdown  li.menuppal ul li a:hover {
    background: #07243a;
}

ul.dropdown  li.menuppal ul li a:visited {
    word-break: break-all;
}

/*
 LEVEL THREE
 */
ul.dropdown ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top:0!important
}

ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

find these selectors and add this css properties there, then it will open every submenu in front of its parent link.

```
    ul.dropdown ul li {position:relative}
    ul.dropdown ul {top:0}
   .dropdown>li>ul {top: 20px;}
```

Comment: the level 2 menus are hiding the level 1 menus !

Comment: @pheromix i have added one more line of code there, it will fix your first-level hiding. Sorry, i missed that

Answer (score 0):

you can try this [link](http://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd). the developer here has said it might cause issue but it hasn't when i tried it

```
#primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

but u need to build it further according to your need.